# Bad request error from UrlFetchApp when fetching the API url

Tags: spring-boot, google-apps-script, web-applications, http-status-code-400, urlfetch

I am getting the following error message: Bad request: [URL] when fetching the API URL using UrlFetchApp.
I need to pass the access token which has been received from the authorization server using a GET request.

My code is:-

```
function run()
 {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        authorizationUrl);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(service.getAccessToken(), null, 2));
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://ffa-int-service-lnhtqfum-zgvbwhku.apps.dev.aro.forgeapp.honeywell.com/get_graph_data';
    var options =
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Authorization' : 'Bearer  ' + service.getAccessToken(),
        },
        muteHttpExceptions : true,
        followRedirects: true
      };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
        authorizationUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client should not repeat the request without modifications.

Comment: I am new to this topic, can you please let me know where I am making mistakes in syntax which is not understood by the server.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong. But it seems the server does. You need to show the actual api server documentation and the request it expects. Only by comparing what the server expects vs what you're sending, we can isolate the issue.

Comment: Also, `Bearer    ` has too many extra spaces after `Bearer`. Try removing it all except one. Also remove this line `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(service.getAccessToken(), null, 2))`

Comment: Maybe it's due to the url unsafe characters like `_` or `-`. Try encoding it?

Comment: Encoding didn't work out, also  _ and - are considered safe characters in a URL, so I don't think that might be causing a problem because the same URL works in postman.